# I can`t find my problem in a Tkinter Python code

Tags: python, tkinter

**Hey,
I am an student and have the exersice to put the following choosing-menu in a tkinter GUI interface. I have started coding, but I don`t find my problem! Can you help me?(This is my first question on this platform, that means, that it can be differently.)
The code:**

```
destination = input("Enter your destination (Edinburgh or Cardiff): ")
travelclass= input("Enter your class (business or economy): ")
meal = input("Do you want on-bord meal(yes or no)? ")
ticket = input("One way or with return(One way or return)? ")

price = 0.00
if destination == "Edinburgh":
    if travelclass == "business":
        if ticket == "return":
            price = 178
        elif ticket == "One way":
            price = 87
    elif travelclass == "economy":
        if ticket == "return":
            if meal == "yes":
                price = 52 + 18
            elif meal == "no":
                price = 52
        elif ticket == "One way":
            if meal == "yes":
                price = 32 + 12
            elif meal == "no":
                price = 32
                price = 5
elif destination == "Cardiff":
    if travelclass == "business":
        if ticket == "return":
            price = 138
        elif ticket == "One way":
            price = 72
    elif travelclass == "economy":
        if ticket == "return":
            if meal == "yes":
                price = 50 + 18
            elif meal == "no":
                price = 50
        elif ticket == "One way":
            if meal == "yes":
                price = 36 + 12
            elif meal == "no":
                price = 36
              
                
print("Your travel costs", price, "£")
```

**And this is my try with tkinter:**

```
from tkinter import*

window=Tk()
window.title = "Train booking"

price = 0.00
destination_label = Label(window, width=30, height=1, text="To")
destination_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

travelclass_label = Label(window, width=30, height=1, text="Business or economy class")
travelclass_label.grid(row=3, column=1)

meal_label = Label(window, width=30, height=1, text="Do you want meal?")
meal_label.grid(row=6, column=1)

ticket_label = Label(window, width=30, height=1, text="One way or with return?")
ticket_label.grid(row=9, column=1)

destination = StringVar()

edinburgh = Radiobutton(window, text="Edinburgh", variable = destination, value = "Edinburgh")
edinburgh.grid(row=1, column=1)
edinburgh.select()
cardiff = Radiobutton(window, text="Cardiff", variable = destination, value = "Cardiff")
cardiff.grid(row=2, column=1)

travelclass = StringVar()

businessclass = Radiobutton(window, text="Businessclass", variable = travelclass, value = "Businessclass")
businessclass.grid(row=4, column=1)
businessclass.select()
economyclass = Radiobutton(window, text="Economyclass", variable = travelclass, value = "Economyclass")
economyclass.grid(row=5, column=1)

meal = StringVar()

yes_meal = Radiobutton(window, text="Yes", variable = meal, value = "Yes")
yes_meal.grid(row=7, column=1)
yes_meal.select()
no_meal = Radiobutton(window, text="No", variable = meal, value = "No")
no_meal.grid(row=8, column=1)

ticket = StringVar()

return_ticket = Radiobutton(window, text="Return", variable = ticket, value = "Return")
return_ticket.grid(row=10, column=1)
return_ticket.select()
one_way_ticket = Radiobutton(window, text="One way", variable = ticket, value = "One way")
one_way_ticket.grid(row=11, column=1)
 
    

    
def change_text(return_ticket, one_way_ticket, no_meal, yes_meal, economyclass, businessclass, cardiff, edinburgh):
    if destination == "Edinburgh":
        if travelclass == "Business":
            if ticket() == "Return":
                price = 178
            elif ticket() == "One way":
                price = 87
        elif travelclass == "Economy":
            if ticket() == "Return":
                if meal == "Yes":
                    price = 52 + 18
                elif meal == "No":
                    price = 52
            elif ticket() == "One way":
                 if meal == "Yes":
                     price = 32 + 12
                 elif meal == "No":
                    price = 32
    elif destination == "Cardiff":
        if travelclass == "Business":
            if ticket == "Return":
                price = 138
            elif ticket == "One way":
                price = 72
        elif travelclass == "Economy":
            if ticket == "Return":
                if meal == "Yes":
                    price = 50 + 18
                elif meal == "No":
                    price = 50
            elif ticket == "One way":
                if meal == "Yes":
                    price = 36 + 12
                elif meal == "No":
                    price = 36
                        



submit = Button(window, text="Submit", width=10, bg="red", command=change_text(return_ticket, one_way_ticket, no_meal, yes_meal, economyclass, businessclass, cardiff, edinburgh))
submit.grid(row=12, column=1)

total_costs = Label(window, width=30, height=1, text= ("Your travel costs", price, "£"))
total_costs.grid(row=13, column=1)



window.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your help and I hope you can find the problem!

Comment: There are few issues: 1) `command=change_text(...)` will execute `change_text()` immediately and assign `None` (`change_text()` does not return anything) to `command` option;  2) arguments of `change_text()` have never been used inside the function; 3) comparing a `StringVar` (`destination`) with a string will always be evaluated as `False`, so no price will be set; 4) `target` is a `StringVar`, so `target()` will raise exception; 5) you need to update the label `total_costs` inside `change_text()`.  If you study your code more clearly and carefully, you can find the above issues yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have tried to correct some issues, but can you write my the line numbers please, that would be really kind. Thank you for your help! And I couldn`t understand what do you mean with target()

Comment: Sorry it is typo. It is 4) `ticket` is a `StringVar`, so `ticket()` will raise exception.